# What is the meaning of Kara's dialogue, "Thank God it vibrates"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, valentines-day

In the movie [Valentine's Day](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0817230/), what is the meaning of Kara's dialogue with Kelvin?

> Kara: My closest relationship is with my BlackBerry.
>
> Kelvin: Right.
>
> Kara: **Thank God it vibrates.**

Every phone vibrates, so why is she thanking God then?

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, from the dialog I would assume however, that this is meant to be "dirty" - like she can use or uses the phone to pleasure herself - I might be wrong though.

Comment: @BojanB There's sexual themes in this film, so this is a pretty safe assumption.

Comment: Remember It is **PG13** movie, never thought it has **dirty** meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She's saying she has a close relationship with an object that vibrates. The implication is that she has the same type of relationship with her phone as she does with a vibrator used for sexual stimulation.